# Comma delimited values sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

From my research online I have discovered two answers to this question which I am trying to stay away from.

1. I cannot modify the table or add a new table because the software is third party and needs the table to remain unmodified.
2. I am trying to stay away from using temporary tables or extra user defined functions.

Here is my issue.

There is a column in the database that is a list of comma-delimited numbers representing days of the week, i.e. (`1,2,4,5,7`).

I am trying to find a way to read that data and find out if there are any rows where that column represents days that are 3 consecutive days.

It should return anything with

```
1,2,3  
2,3,4  
3,4,5  
5,6,7  
1,,,,,6,7  
1,2,,,,,7
```

But if the column has 1,2,3,4 it should not return twice. There are a lot of rows that have 2,3,4,5,6 and any solution I've come up with will return that 3 times.

Preferably, I would like to create a stored procedure to pass in a number and look for that number of consecutive days. So if 5 is passed in, it will look for anything that is marked for 5 consecutive days.

Is there another option other than using extra tables? If so can you show me how to do make this work? I am not new to SQL but there are a lot of more advanced querying techniques I am not familiar with.

Comment: one option would be to create an additional table and normalize the data there. You can leave your original table unchanged, but use the normalized table for queries like this.

Comment: What database are you using?  (Please tag the question with the database.)  Are the numbers always in order?

Comment: I know it it sql2008, but not sure if r2 or not. I would love to normalize the database but again, it's a third party application that is reading the data and I have no control over the source code or the table itself.

Comment: ... If you can't control the source or the table itself, how would your stored-proc be called?  If you _can_ write a stored proc (and have it be called), what's preventing you from creating other db objects that would let you get around this?

Comment: I can create a stored procedure, and we are using the information from the table in a report. I just can't modify the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So if 5 is passed in, it will look for anything that is marked for 5 consecutive days.

You won't be able to do that without dynamic sql, because you want to support wrapping from 7 back to 1. I could write a query that would do it for you in a single statement if you didn't care about wrapping from the end of the week back to the beginning, but with that requirement I don't see how to do it without building a dynamic sql string in the procedure, which I don't have time to play with right now (maybe someone else will take that idea and run with it).

With that option defeated for now, I can do this instead:

```
WHERE
    (     col like '1,2,3%' 
       OR col like '%2,3,4%'
       OR col like '%3,4,5%'
       OR col like '%4,5,6%'
       OR col like '%5,6,7'
       OR col like '1%6,7'
       OR col like '1,2%7'
    )
```

This should be better than checking individual numbers as shown in another answer, because there are fewer pattern matches to complete. However, *it only works if we can guarantee the sort order*. We also need to know in advance how the commas are spaced between numbers, but we can fix that issue if necessary by replacing all commas and/or spaces with an empty string (and adjusting the patterns accordingly).

One more thought here: I realized that I can support a day count argument, if you can manage sneaking an additional table into the db somewhere. The table would look something like this:

```
 create Table DayPatterns (Days int, Pattern varchar(13) )
```

and the data in the table would look like this:

```
1   1%
1   %2%
1   %3%
...
2   1,2%
2   %2,3%
2   %3,4%
2   %4,5%
...
2   1%7
...
3   1,2,3%
3   %2,3,4%
...
3   1%6,7
3   1,2%7
...
7   1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

Hopefully you get the idea on how to fill that out. With that table in hand, you can JOIN against the table with a query like this:

```
INNER JOIN DayPatterns p ON p.Days = @ConsecutiveDays AND col LIKE p.Pattern
```

The key to making that work (aside from needing to be able to create that table somewhere) is also doing a GROUP BY on the correct columns. Otherwise, you'll end up with the same problem you have right now, where matching multiple possible consecutive day patterns will duplicate your results.

Finally, of course you know that most any schema that includes csv data is broken, but since you can't seem to fix this, hopefully one of these ideas will help.

Comment: The data will always be in numerical order, so I will give this a try tomorrow and play with it. I will let you know my final solution.

Answer (score 1):

The following brute force method will work in all databases:

```
select (case when col like '%1%' and col like '%2%' and col like '%3%' then 1
             when col like '%2%' and col like '%3%' and col like '%4%' then 1
             when col like '%3%' and col like '%4%' and col like '%5%' then 1
             when col like '%4%' and col like '%5%' and col like '%6%' then 1
             when col like '%5%' and col like '%6%' and col like '%7%' then 1
             when col like '%6%' and col like '%7%' and col like '%1%' then 1
             when col like '%7%' and col like '%1%' and col like '%2%' then 1
             else 0
        end) as HasThreeConsecutiveDays
```

It returns a 0/1 flag if three days are consecutive.